# Eliminate a parameterization from system of equations

Tags: analysis, systems-of-equations

Let $x(t) = x_0 e^{\lambda_1t} $, $y(t) = y_0 e^{\lambda_2t} $

A book I am reading has performed the following change to remove the parameter $t$:

Let $y = cx^{\lambda_2 / \lambda_1}$ where $c = \frac {y_0}{(x_0)^{\lambda_2 / \lambda_1}}  $

I'm having trouble seeing exactly how to make this transformation.  Can anyone point this out?

Comment: Find $e^t$ from both equations and equalize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x_0 \ne 0$, $y_0 \ne 0$ and $\lambda_i \ne 0$ we can solve for $t$ and equate there:
$$
\begin{align}
t = \ln(x/x_0) (1/\lambda_1) &= \ln(y/y_0) (1/\lambda_2) \Rightarrow \\
y &= y_0 \, e^{\ln(x/x_0) (\lambda_2 / \lambda_1)} \\
&= y_0 \, (x / x_0)^{(\lambda_2 / \lambda_1)} \\
&= \frac{y_0}{x_0^{(\lambda_2 / \lambda_1)}} x^{(\lambda_2 / \lambda_1)} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Okay I feel dumb now.  Time for bed.  Thanks